# Spring 4 and RabbitMQ json type

Tags: json, spring, rabbitmq, unmarshalling, spring-rabbit

I'm really stuck with cast Rabbit response to POJO. How to do it properly? On sprin.io just no practical example. 
So I'm trying to do it with this

```
@Bean
public DefaultClassMapper typeMapper() {
    DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    Map<String, Class> idClassMapping = new HashMap<String, Class>();
    idClassMapping.put("range", Loan.class);
    typeMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
    //typeMapper.setDefaultType(Loan.class);
    return typeMapper;
}

@Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(DefaultClassMapper defaultClassMapper){
        JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new JsonMessageConverter();
        jsonMessageConverter.setClassMapper(defaultClassMapper);
        return jsonMessageConverter;
    }
```

"range" actually fake value from example. Also this really doesn't work type problemn on .setIdClassMapping() . Also I can't use default mapper because serve send header without type hinting field. And I have no control on this remote server. Data format always JSON.

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve __TypeId__ in header
```

Any suggestions working example for marshalling/demarshalling Java objects. I have completely different class for send back value from my code. I'm using java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own `ClassMapper` - don't use the default one if your decision criteria to choose the class type is not compatible with its internals.

Or, you can subclass the `DefaultClassMapper` and override `getClassIdFieldName()` to tell it which message property to use.